# What is the meaning of سعدیک and و الشرّ لیس الیک in this prayer of Istiftah?

Tags: arabic, dua, arabic-translation

The following is part of the Istiftah prayer narrated to be cited by Prophet -p.b.u.h- :

> وجّهت وجهي للّذي فطر السموات والأرض حنيفاً، وما أنا من المشركين، إنّ
>   صلاتي ونسكي ومحياي ومماتي لله ربّ العالمين، لا شريك له وبذلك أمرت وأنا
>   من المسلمين، اللهمّ أنت الملك لا إله إلا أنت، أنت ربّي وأنا عبدك، ظلمت
>   نفسي، اعترفت بذنبي، فاغفر لي ذنوبي جميعاً، إنّه لا يغفر الذّنوب إلا
>   أنت، واهدني لأحسن الأخلاق، لا يهدي لأحسنها إلا أنت، واصرف عنّي سيئها
>   لا يصرف عنّي سيئها إلا أنت، لبّيك و**سعديك** والخير بين يديك، **والشرّ
>   ليس إليك**، أنا بك وإليك، تباركت وتعاليت أستغفرك وأتوب إليك

1- What's meant by *sa'daik* (سعدیک)?

2- What is exactly meant by و الشرّ لیس الیک?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The word `سعديك`  is derived from the noun `سَعادة`  which means happiness, so `سعديك` means to make you happy, or for your happiness.

   يقالُ في الدعاءِ : لبّيْكَ وسعْدَيْكَ : إسْعَاداً لك بَعْدَ إِسعاد
2. The sentence `و الشرّ لیس الیک` is composed of the word `الشرّ` which means `evil`, our God is way too far to do anything evil to us(his creations), by saying that the Hadith want to mention that everything good is between God hands(metaphorically, God does not has hands or body) and that God is not known to be evil and has nothing to do with it.