# Do I have to say this dua before every salah?

Tags: salat, dua

**Inni wajjahtu wajhiya lillahi fatiri s-mawaati wal ard hanii-fa-n wamaa ana minal mushrikeen.**

For example, let's say I want to pray Maghrib (3 raka'a fard and 2 raka'a sunnah). So, I first recite this dua and pray 3 raka'a fard. But before praying the 2 raka'a sunnah, do I have to recite this dua again? Does this dua go before every salah?

Comment: This is one of the formulations for dua' al istiftah. This dua' is optional and one can say it after the takbir to start a prayer.

Comment: So it's not fard? I can just pray salah without saying this dua at all?

Comment: Yes the Maliki school doesn't even have it among the mustahabat of the prayer.

Comment: See also http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25644/what-is-the-meaning-of-these-words-in-this-prayer-of-istiftah?s=1|0.8907 and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30493/thana-dua-isteftah-is-necessary-on-missing-rakah-or-not?noredirect=1&lq=1, see also this fatwa in Arabic https://islamqa.info/ar/242032 (only so far)

Comment: @Medi1Saif your comments answer the question completely and than people like me don't want to repeat what you said in answer, so the question remains unanswered for long time, and that's not good for this beta site. :/

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal In this case i was expecting the question to be closed as a duplicate. Some times I post a comment to show that an answer exist on the site or to give a first aid. I don't want to answer the same question 10 times, feel free to answer, you can even use my quotes, lately the firewall at my office hinders me to open almost all of my sources, so I'll hardly be able to answer questions I've on my to do list.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Jazakumullah khair

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thana (Dua Isteftah) is necessary on missing Rakah or not?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30493/thana-dua-isteftah-is-necessary-on-missing-rakah-or-not)